# I'm trying to get started with SDN-WISE

Tags: maven, pom.xml, sdn

I'm following the steps of [https://sdnwiselab.github.io/docs/guides/GetStarted](Get Started with SDN-WISE)

On the Step 4: Run the Controller when I execute the line `mvn package`

I got the following error

```
user@instant-contiki:~/01-GetStarted$ mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building 01-GetStarted
[INFO]    task-segment: [package]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-bundle:jar': Cannot find parent: net.java:jvnet-parent for project: com.sun.jersey:jersey-project:pom:1.19 for project com.sun.jersey:jersey-project:pom:1.19
  com.sun.jersey:jersey-bundle:jar:1.19

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

Path to dependency: 
    1) com.github.sdnwiselab:01-GetStarted:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

here it is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <groupId>com.github.sdnwiselab</groupId>
    <artifactId>01-GetStarted</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    
    <name>01-GetStarted</name>
    <description>The stateful Software Defined Networking solution for WIreless SEnsor Networks</description>
    <url>http://sdn-wise.dieei.unict.it</url>   
    <inceptionYear>2014</inceptionYear>
    
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <netbeans.hint.license>gpl30</netbeans.hint.license>
        <fully.qualified.main.class>com.github.sdnwiselab.sdnwise.loader.SdnWise</fully.qualified.main.class>
    </properties>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>${fully.qualified.main.class}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                            <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                            <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        </configuration>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.sdnwiselab</groupId>
            <artifactId>sdn-wise-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graphstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>gs-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.jodah</groupId>
            <artifactId>expiringmap</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graphstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>gs-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```